# Add UIView and UILabel programmatically on Mac OS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uikit

I am trying to add a UIView then a UILabel as a subview on Mac OS and iPad.  if I call the following function in loadView() and run the iPad simulator the background turns white and my UILabel appears in the middle where its supposed to.  If I run the Mac OS simulator, the background turns white but I have no text.  The app is a UIKit app with the checkbox to run on Mac using Mac Catalyst checked.

Any ideas as to why its not showing my UILabel when I run on Mac OS Sim?

```
func coreIdea() {
    
    view = UIView()
    coreIdeaLabel = UILabel()
    
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    coreIdeaLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    coreIdeaLabel.textAlignment = .center
    coreIdeaLabel.text = "CoreIdea"
    coreIdeaLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
    
    view.addSubview(coreIdeaLabel)
            
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        coreIdeaLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        coreIdeaLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at this in the view debugger? My guess is that the default color of UILabel is white. Try setting `textColor` to either an explicit color or `.label`. You might also want to use `.systemBackground` for the background color to automatically support dark mode.

Comment: Thank you!  I woke up this morning thinking to myself I bet the text colour is white ‍♂️!  I open this up to find your answer !  I changed the background to systemBackground and it works fine.  Thank again